# Is there a software to be able to view monitors of multiple users on the same network

Tags: multi-monitor, screen-sharing

I'm looking for a software to be able to simply view the monitors of computers on the same network.

My children are studying in an online school (currently working abroad for few years, not homeschooling) and I want to be able to see they are actually studying during the sessions.

I simply need to view, not block the screen, no remote control or anything. Preferably, if I could do the from my mobile phone when away too, but being able to view **all the monitors simultaneously** from my computer (which is on the same network) is enough.

- All the computers use Windows, mine too.
- I have 5 to 8 computers on the network (neighbour's children too).

Is there a software solution for this? Preferably free.